# How to get tasks assigned for a particular group id in jBPM6?

Tags: jbpm

I have modified Evaluation business process so that HREvaluation and PMEvaluation tasks are only assigned to the group id. Even though, I have overridden UserGroupCallback (which is executing), when I get the tasks assign to john user, it does not display any group tasks. 
I used the method,

List status = Arrays.asList(new Status[] { Status.Ready });

list = taskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwnerByStatus("john", status, "en-UK");

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that John is in the group that the HREvaluation and PMEvaluation are being assigned.

Comment: Thanks a lot salaboy. After adding the following to ApplicationScooped class, the issue is gone. @Produces
    public UserInfo produceUserInfo(){
     this.userInfo = new DefaultUserInfo(true);
     return this.userInfo;
    }